# How can I draw this table 1?

Tags: tables, itemize

How can I draw the following table in LaTeX?

Can I add the itemize inside the table like the image below?

[image]

I tried this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | m{5em} | m{1cm}|  }
  \hline
  \rowcolor{gray!40}
  \multicolumn{2}
    {|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr5em+1cm+1cm+6\tabcolsep\relax}|}
    {Very Long text here and centred}\\
  \hline
  \noalign{\vspace{1ex}}
  \hline
  Description & ong text bla bla bla bla bla bla   \\
  \hline
  Adition & long text bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Your code example is not even close to what you like to obtain...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                  topsep= 0pt,
                  partopsep=0pt,
                  leftmargin= *,
                  label=\textendash,
                  before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                  after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}
                  }
\bfseries
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | l | X | }
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}{\cellcolor{gray!30}
    Very long text here and centered
    Very long text here and centered
    Very long text here and centered}    \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}                    \\
    \hline
Description &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \end{itemize}          \\
    \hline
Addition    & long text bla bla bla bla long text bla bla bla bla\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

In the case that there will be only one line text in the first table row, then you can do this row write as:

```
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!30} Very long text here and centered}    \\
```

**Edit:**
in the cases when you have more tables with lists in the cells, you can use macro `\AtBeginEnvironment` from the package `etoolbox` and move list setup from `center` or `table` float environment to document preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
    \setlist[itemize,1]{nosep,     
                        topsep     = 0pt,
                        partopsep  = 0pt,
                        leftmargin = *,
                        label      = \textendash,
                        before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                        after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                        }  }
```

**Addendum:**

I would never get such a table for myself. I prefer something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,labelfont=bf,justification=centerlast]{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
    \setlist[itemize,1]{nosep,     
                        topsep     = 0pt,
                        partopsep  = 0pt,
                        leftmargin = *,
                        label      = \textendash,
                        before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                        after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                        }  }

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Very long text here and centered
    Very long text here and centered
    Very long text here and centered}
\label{tab: my table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ l X }
    \toprule
Description &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \end{itemize}          \\
    \addlinespace
Addition    & long text bla bla bla bla long text bla bla bla bla\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: one question please I already use itemize and when i add this code its disorder the itemize for my other work in document

Comment: @Jabir, corrected. its definition had to be "local", in the environment where the table is placed.

Comment: @Zarko: you  should use a `\textendash` as a label for itemize, not a hyphen.

Comment: @Bernard, thank you for pointing this. i will correct asap.

Comment: @https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427064/itemize-inside-itemize-and-missing-some-lines-in-box-of-table I'm interested of your answer would you see my question

Answer (score 4):

The following reproduces the look of your table. You'll have to adjust the `\dimexpr5em+1cm+1cm+6\tabcolsep\relax` to match the width of your table. You'll need two `\tabcolsep` per column plus the width of each column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | m{5em} | m{1cm}| m{1cm} | } 
  \hline
  \rowcolor{gray!40}
  \multicolumn{3}
    {|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr5em+1cm+1cm+6\tabcolsep\relax}|}
    {Very Long text here and centred}\\
  \hline
  \noalign{\vspace{1ex}}
  \hline
  cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text& cell2 & cell3 \\ 
  \hline
  cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
  \hline
  cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes but I would like to create the exact table in image thanks

Comment: @Jabir why do you give us an MWE with so little in common then? Your column counts don't match and the text is different, too.

Comment: I really appreciated your help

Comment: @Jabir if so say it with votes.

Comment: @Skillmon, so far op haven't rights to vote. instead of him/her i will do this :-)

Comment: now since I got 15 point I voted for you :)