# itemize inside itemize and some of borders around the gray title section are missing

Tags: tables, itemize

I'm interested of th Following Question [How can I draw this table 1?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426947/how-can-i-draw-this-table-1/426951#426951)

I would like to know how can I use itemize inside 'itemize' inside table I tried code of @Zarko but with no luck besides I wonder why I can't  get all 4 borders around the gray title section

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                  topsep= 0pt,
                  partopsep=0pt,
                  leftmargin= *,
                  label=\textendash,
                  before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                  after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}
                  }
\bfseries
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | l | X | }
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}{\cellcolor{gray!30}
    Very long text here and centered
    Very long text here and centered
    Very long text here and centered}    \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}                    \\
    \hline
Description &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \end{itemize}          \\
    \hline
Addition    & long text bla bla bla bla long text bla bla bla bla\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In order to get the vertical spacing around the itemize environment (top and bottom) inside of a table cell right, one has to add negative spaces (`before` and `after` options of `setlist`). They interfere with the nested `itemize` enviroment.

Comment: @leandriis Could you please write answer to show me that

Comment: I do get all 4 borders around the gray title section, but some get invisible at smaller display sizes due to the required scaling and the gray background  (probably rounding errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bases on my answer on the question [how-can-i-draw-this-table-1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426947/how-can-i-draw-this-table-1/426951#426951):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{center}{%
    \setlist[itemize,1]{nosep,
                        topsep     = 0pt,
                        partopsep  = 0pt,
                        leftmargin = *,
                        label      = \textendash,
                        before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                        after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                        }
    \setlist[itemize]{  nosep,
                        leftmargin=*,
                        label = $\bullet$
                      } }

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\bfseries
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | l | X | }
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}%
                 p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}{\cellcolor{gray!30}
    Very long text here and centered
    Very long text here and centered
    Very long text here and centered}    \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}                    \\
    \hline
Description &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                    \begin{itemize}
                    \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                    \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                    \end{itemize}
                \end{itemize}          \\
    \hline
Addition    & long text bla bla bla bla long text bla bla bla bla\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't see the borders until I zoom pdf is there any possible to be showing without zooming

Comment: this seems to be problem of your pdf viewer. i can see borders very well in Sumatra as well in Adobe Reader DC. now i notice, that the calculation of `multicolumn` has error: i forgot to consider `\arrayrulewidth`. now is corrected. if you like to have thicker array rules, you can change them with `\setlength\arrayrulewidth{<desired thikness>}`

Comment: with your new update I got problem

Comment: ups, one  `r` in word `\arrayrulewidth` was lost :-(. sorry for any inconvenience. now corrected

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427154/how-to-draw-simple-table

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code  with a nested itemize, and various improvements and simplifications:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tabularx, hhline}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
        \makeatletter
        \newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
        \makeatother
     \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{ >{\arraybackslash\compress}p{#1}}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{center}
    \setlist[itemize]{wide=0pt, nosep, leftmargin= * }
    \setlist[itemize, 1]{ label=\textendash, after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
    \setlist[itemize, 2]{ label=\textgreater}
    \setlength{\doublerulesep}{12pt}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \bfseries
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | l | X | }
        \hhline{--}
    \rowcolor{WhiteSmoke!70!Lavender}\multicolumn{2}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}{%
        Very long text here and centered
        Very long text here and centered
        Very long text here and centered} \\
     % \hline \noalign{\vspace*{12pt}}
    %\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
        \hhline{==}
    Description & \begin{itemize}
                    \item long text bla bla bla bla
                    \item long text bla bla bla bla
                    \begin{itemize}[]
                    \item long text bla bla bla bla
                    \item long text bla bla bla bla
                    \item long text bla bla bla bla
                    \item long text bla bla bla bla
                    \end{itemize}
                    \item long text bla bla bla bla
                    \item long text bla bla bla bla
                    \end{itemize} \\
        \hhline{--}
    Addition & long text bla bla bla bla long text bla bla bla bla\\
        \hhline{--}
    \end{tabularx}
        \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- The first table does not include the `before` and `after` options in order to correct the spacing above and below the `itemize` environment.
- The second table includes these options. As one can see, the negative `vspace`s interfere with nested `itemize` environments, as they add up.
- The third table does again not contain the `before` and `after` options, but includes some manual adjustments in order to get rid of the unnecessary white space above and below the first level `itemize` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                  topsep= 0pt,
                  partopsep=0pt,
                  leftmargin= *,
                  label=\textendash,
                  %before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                  %after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}
                  }

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | l | X | }
    \hline
Description &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                  \begin{itemize}
                  \item short text
                  \item short text
                  \end{itemize}
                \end{itemize}          \\
    \hline
Addition    & long text bla bla bla bla long text bla bla bla bla\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}

\begin{center}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                  topsep= 0pt,
                  partopsep=0pt,
                  leftmargin= *,
                  label=\textendash,
                  before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                  after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}
                  }

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | l | X | }
    \hline
Description &   \begin{itemize} 
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                  \begin{itemize}
                  \item short text
                  \item short text
                  \end{itemize}
                \end{itemize}          \\
    \hline
Addition    & long text bla bla bla bla long text bla bla bla bla\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}


    \begin{center}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                  topsep= 0pt,
                  partopsep=0pt,
                  leftmargin= *,
                  label=\textendash,
                  %before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                  %after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}
                  }

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | l | X | }
    \hline
Description &   \begin{itemize} \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                  \begin{itemize}
                  \item short text
                  \item short text
                  \end{itemize}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
                \end{itemize}          \\
    \hline
Addition    & long text bla bla bla bla long text bla bla bla bla\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

The last table can also be produced with the following MWE, which makes use of two different, new defined `itemize`-like environments for first-level and subsequent-level `itemize` environments inside table cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{tabitemizefirst}{itemize}{1}
\newlist{tabitemizesecond}{itemize}{1}

\setlist[tabitemizefirst]{nosep,
                  topsep= 0pt,
                  partopsep=0pt,
                  leftmargin= *,
                  label=\textendash,
                  before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                  after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}
                  }

\setlist[tabitemizesecond]{nosep,
                  topsep= 0pt,
                  partopsep=0pt,
                  leftmargin= *,
                  label=\textendash,
                  }

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | l | X | }
    \hline
Description &   \begin{tabitemizefirst}
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                \item   long text bla bla bla bla
                  \begin{tabitemizesecond}
                  \item short text
                  \item short text
                  \end{tabitemizesecond}
                \end{tabitemizefirst}          \\
    \hline
Addition    & long text bla bla bla bla long text bla bla bla bla\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```