# How to draw this table

Tags: tables

I would like to draw the following table 
[image]
here is my code :

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, makecell, rotating} %
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | p{5cm} |}
    \hline
      \rowcolor{blue!30} \rothead{Cell 1} &   \rowcolor{blue!30} \rothead{Cell 2}  &   \rowcolor{blue!30} Summary \\ \hline
    \rothead{very long vertical text } & \rothead{very long vertical text }  &   \begin{itemize} \item very long text up here right here   \item very long text up here right here  \item very long text up here right here   \end{itemize}\\ \hline
    \rothead{very long vertical text } & \rothead{very long vertical text }  &   \begin{itemize} \item very long text up here right here   \item very long text up here right here  \item very long text up here right here   \end{itemize}\\ \hline
      \rothead{very long vertical text } & \rothead{very long vertical text }  &   \begin{itemize} \item very long text up here right here   \item very long text up here right here  \item very long text up here right here   \end{itemize}\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces :

[image]

Comment: Well, you seem to have it. What is your problem?

Comment: in what is this question different from your https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427154/how-to-draw-simple-table? there you have answer which solve your problem ...

Comment: @Bernard nope i don't have it yet, it's produces ugly table

Comment: @Zarko Yes it's different from that question could you produces this one

Comment: no, it is not different so much. see answer below.

Answer (score 3):

is this close enough to what you like to have?

[image]

- it is based on combination on answers to your previous questions [How to draw simple table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427154/how-to-draw-simple-table) and [itemize-inside-itemize-and-some-of-borders-around-the-gray-title-section-are-mis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427064/itemize-inside-itemize-and-some-of-borders-around-the-gray-title-section-are-mis)
- rotating cells with `Cell 1` and `Cell 2` gives ugly result since `makecell` doesn't work well with `colortbl` which is called by `[table]{xcolor}`. if this text are short enough (as is in your table example), then is no sense to rotate them

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, makecell, rotating} %
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{%
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                        topsep     = 0pt,
                        partopsep  = 0pt,
                        leftmargin = *,
                        label      = $\bullet$,
                        before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                        after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                     } }
\makeatletter
\def\@rothead[#1]#2{\thead{\\[-.65\normalbaselineskip] % for centering vertical text
  \turn{\cellrotangle}\thead[#1]{#2}\endturn}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | p{5cm} |}
    \hline
\rowcolor{blue!30} 
Cell 1    
    &  Cell 2  
        &   Summary                             \\ \hline
\multirow{6}{*}{\rothead[c]{very long\\ vertical text}}% text had to be manually  
                                                       % broken into two lines 
    & \multirow{6}{*}{\rothead[c]{very long\\ vertical text}}   
        &   \begin{itemize} 
        \item very long text up here right here   
        \item very long text up here right here  
        \item very long text up here right here   
        \end{itemize}                           \\ \hline
\multirow{6}{*}{\rothead[c]{very long\\ vertical text}}
    & \multirow{6}{*}{\rothead[c]{very long\\ vertical text}}
        &   \begin{itemize} 
        \item very long text up here right here   
        \item very long text up here right here  
        \item very long text up here right here   
        \end{itemize}                           \\ \hline
\multirow{6}{*}{\rothead[c]{very long\\ vertical text}}
    & \multirow{6}{*}{\rothead[c]{very long\\ vertical text}}
        &   \begin{itemize} 
        \item very long text up here right here   
        \item very long text up here right here  
        \item very long text up here right here 
            \end{itemize}                       \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

**addendum (1):**

since `\rothead` doesn't work well with `colortbl` which is called by `[table]{xcolor}` for rotating cells `Cell 1` and `Cell 2` is better to use `\rotatebox` from the package `graphicx` than `\rothead`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, makecell, rotating} %
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{%
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                        topsep     = 0pt,
                        partopsep  = 0pt,
                        leftmargin = *,
                        label      = $\bullet$,
                        before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                        after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                       } }
\makeatletter
\def\@rothead[#1]#2{\thead{\\[-.65\normalbaselineskip]
  \turn{\cellrotangle}\thead[#1]{#2}\endturn}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | p{5cm} |}
    \hline
\rowcolor{blue!30}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ Cell 1 }}% observe added spaces before and after text in cell
    &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ Cell 2 }}
        &   Summary                             \\ \hline
\multirow{6}{*}{\rothead[c]{very long\\ vertical text}}
    & \multirow{6}{*}{\rothead[c]{very long\\ vertical text}}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item very long text up here right here
        \item very long text up here right here
        \item very long text up here right here
        \end{itemize}                           \\ \hline
\multirow{6}{*}{\rothead[c]{very long\\ vertical text}}
    & \multirow{6}{*}{\rothead[c]{very long\\ vertical text}}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item very long text up here right here
        \item very long text up here right here
        \item very long text up here right here
        \end{itemize}                           \\ \hline
\multirow{6}{*}{\rothead[c]{very long\\ vertical text}}
    & \multirow{6}{*}{\rothead[c]{very long\\ vertical text}}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item very long text up here right here
        \item very long text up here right here
        \item very long text up here right here
            \end{itemize}                       \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which givews

[image]

**addendum (2):**

regarding your additional demand in your comment: to have rotated long text in one column can make trouble to you. it is in `multirow` environment, which vertical size is equal to sum of heights of spanned lines. this means, that can happens that you will need to additional (empty) vertical space on the next columns. the result will probably be (very) ugly ...

anyway, the following example has vertical lines in one lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, makecell, rotating} %
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{%
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                        topsep     = 0pt,
                        partopsep  = 0pt,
                        leftmargin = *,
                        label      = $\bullet$,
                        before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                        after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                       } }
\makeatletter
\def\@rothead[#1]#2{\thead{\\[-.65\normalbaselineskip]
  \turn{\cellrotangle}\thead[#1]{#2}\endturn}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | p{5cm} |}
    \hline
\rowcolor{blue!30}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ Cell 1 }}% observe added spaces before and after text in cell
    &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ Cell 2 }}
        &   Summary                             \\ \hline
\multirow{10}{*}{\rothead[c]{very long vertical text}}
    & \multirow{10}{*}{\rothead[c]{very long vertical text}}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item very long text up here right here
        \item very long text up here right here
        \item very long text up here right here
        \item very long text up here right here
        \item very long text up here right here
        \end{itemize}                           \\ \hline
\multirow{10}{*}{\rothead[c]{very long vertical text}}
    & \multirow{10}{*}{\rothead[c]{very long vertical text}}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item very long text up here right here
        \item very long text up here right here
        \item very long text up here right here
        \item very long text up here right here
        \item very long text up here right here
        \end{itemize}                           \\ \hline
\multirow{10}{*}{\rothead[c]{very long vertical text}}
    & \multirow{10}{*}{\rothead[c]{very long vertical text}}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item very long text up here right here
        \item very long text up here right here
        \item very long text up here right here
        \item very long text up here right here
        \item very long text up here right here
            \end{itemize}                       \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wait for me please to test it by the way +1 already

Comment: But Cell 1 and 2 i want them in vertical position and summary centerd in cell

Comment: i say in answer, why this is not good to do. if you anyway like to have in vertical position, than enclose them in `\rothead{...}`

Comment: when I add rothead{...} it's gives me bad looks

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOfST.jpg

Comment: i told you this! see my addendum to my answer.

Comment: Should I post new question for this case if text are long

Comment: How can i let the cell contains very lext and keep it vertical without break it into tow lines

Comment: You can try to put it in an `\mbox`.

Comment: @Bernard  could you add it in answer

Comment: @Educ: I didn't try it, as you didn't an example of the real situation. There might problems with horizontal lines touching the text. Could post an example code?

Comment: my code already contains " very long text very long text very long text "

Comment: Thank you but how can i add additional (empty) vertical space on the next column

Comment: in one of my previous answer i show you, how to do this. however, i would reconsider your table design. the my second solution is the right way (to my opinion, of course).