# escaping brackets in description environment

Tags: brackets, delimiters, description

i didn't find a working solution to escape brackets `[ ]` inside a description.

```
\begin{description}
\item[\$ chmod [options] mode \textless filename \textgreater] change filepermissions: chmod -v u+rwx myfile.txt
\end{description}
```

should produce:

**$ chmod [options] mode**  change filepermissions: chmod -v u+rwx myfile.txt

Comment: `\item[\texttt{\$ chmod [options] mode <filename>}]` If you don't want a typewriter font, just remove `\texttt` (not the braces) and use `\textless` and `\textgreater`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put the brackets in a group:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[\$ chmod {[options]} mode \textless filename \textgreater] change filepermissions: chmod -v u+rwx myfile.txt
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please make these cells able to contains very long text and keep it vertical without break it into tow lines in this question     https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429128/how-to-draw-this-table